# Need to ImageView to download image, not use cache

Tags: java, android, bitmap, download, imageview

I have and imageview that downloads a bitmap:

```
InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
```

The imagview then scales the image:

```
android:maxWidth="75dp"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"  
android:scaleType="fitCenter"
```

The problem is, I need to use the full sized image later, and when I try to download it again, it appears that the cached, scaled version gets used. Is there a way to force a download and not use the cached version?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Probably it's the server problem. You can figure it out by adding any empty param to your url

For example

```
urldisplay += ("?" + UUID.randomUUID().toString() + "=");
InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, but this does suggestion does not seem to change anything.